# Salesforce Lightning Limitations Winter '17

Tags: email, lightning, email-template, winter17

### Salesforce Lightning Limitations in Winter '17?

I have looked up and down and cannot find if (or when) Email Templates from Classic org are avaliable in the Winter '17 release of Lightning.

i found in the [Summer '16 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_sales_email_sfx.htm), what is not available:

- Mass Email is not available.
- Mass Email Merge is not available.
- Email templates created in Salesforce Classic can’t be used in
  Lightning Experience, and vice versa.
- Email is not available for cases, campaigns, person accounts, or
  custom objects.
- Text, HTML with letterhead, and Visualforce templates are not
  available. Templates in Lightning Experience are custom HTML.
- You can’t attach files from Salesforce Files Connect, such as Google
  Drive files or Microsoft SharePoint® files, to emails in Lightning
  Experience.
- Automatic BCC, which lets users automatically receive copies of sent
  emails, is not available in Lightning Experience.

My Major Dilema about Switching to Lightning is:

- Email templates created in Salesforce Classic can’t be used in
  Lightning Experience, and vice versa.

I found in the Winter '17 Release Notes a section Called "[Whats Not Available in Lightning Winter '17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lex_gaps_limitations.htm)" but it mentions nothing about email limitations.

Question: was this limitation of not having the ability to use email templates made in SF Classic in the Summer '16 release still unavaliable in Winter '17 Release?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a global list of [What’s Not Available in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations.htm)
in Salesforce Help which get's updated with every release.

You can find the Email Template related details under the [Productivity Features](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_productivity.htm) section and here's the extract

---

**Email Templates**

Email templates in Lightning Experience support rich text and are sent as HTML.

Email templates created in Salesforce Classic (text, HTML with letterhead, and Visualforce) can’t be used in Lightning Experience and vice versa. However, admins can add or remove Salesforce Classic email templates from Lightning Experience Setup.

All templates created in Lightning Experience are public. Any attachment in an email becomes public when that email is sent. Users no longer have to share the templates they create.

---

So to answer your Question, Email templates created in classic are not yet fully supported in lex.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your email template using Classic Email Templates and use your letterhead and logo (saved in documents). If you are using Lightning, there are 2 "Email" buttons on the page layout, one allows you to send Classic Email templates and the other one does not. Be sure to add the right "Email" button to your page and when you push the button to insert an email template, Classic Email Templates now appears in the drop-down menu.